# Confidence Interval for a Percent Change

Tags: confidence-interval, stata, percentage

A mentor has asked me to calculate the 95% confidence interval surrounding a percent change.

To help frame the question, I have calculated the incidence of a disease within the population as follows:

**Period 1:**
  # with disease = 22
  population at risk = 2836131
  incidence per 100,000 = 0.78
  95% confidence interval = 0.49, 1.17

**Period 2:**
  # with disease = 46
  population at risk = 8011777
  incidence per 100,000 = 0.57
  95% confidence interval = 0.42, 0.77

For reference, I calculated the above incidence rates and their confidence intervals by assuming a Poisson distribution in Stata:

cii 2836131 22 , poisson

cii 8011777 46 , poisson

The end result is that I have reported the decline in the incidence of disease (0.78/100,000 to 0.57/100,000), which is a 26% decrease.  My mentor would like to see a 95% confidence interval surrounding the percent change (26%) ...

If anyone could help by providing a reference or a suggestion of where to go with this, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Are those cumulative incidences or incident rates? Anyway, you could take a look at the `csi` and `iri` commands. They calculate the Attributable fraction among the exposed (which is what you've calculated) together with a CI. For example `csi 22 46 2836109 8011731`

Comment: maybe I'm over-suspicious here, but pay attention that those CIs make sense if the exposed and unexposed groups are independent. Since you're talking about "Period 1" and "Period 2" are you sure the 2 groups you're comparing are actually independent? Again, I don't really know what you're doing here but I just wanted to give you a heads up. @user17239